# ruby conditional logic

Tags: ruby

My program I want to make is almost complete but I am having trouble with expression operator.I cant seem right expressions for it. I want to return “Integers close” if by one for numbers 2 and 3. I also want number 1 "far” differing from both other values by 2 or more.

example

(1, 2, 10) → Integers close
(5, 1, 9) → Integers far

```
loop do

      puts"enter each number then hit enter quit to end"
    number1 = STDIN.gets
    number1.chop!
    number2 = STDIN.gets
    number2.chop!
    number3 = STDIN.gets
    number3.chop!

    numbers = [number1,number2,number3]
    puts numbers.inspect
    if number1 > number2 or number3 then
      puts "Integers close"
    end
      if number2 < number3  then
        puts"Integers far"
      end
      break if number1 == "quit"
    end
```

Comment: `if number1 > number2 || number1 > number3 then...`

Comment: With the caveat that it makes no sense to test for `quit` last.

Comment: You're not checking the differences. You'll need to do some subtraction. Also from your description I'm not clear if you intend to report "far" if *all* numbers differ by 2 or more, or are you just comparing the first with the others?

Comment: Operator precedence? It should be `if((number1 > number 2) or (number1 > number3)) then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if number1 > number2 or number3 then
      puts "Integers close"
    end
```

This isn't doing what you want it to. This will evaluate to `true` whenever `number1 > number2` or number is not nil (which is impossible, since it will always be at least the empty string.) As a matter of style, `then` is unnecessary.

For your program, you don't want the user to have to enter numbers 2 and 3 if they want to quit. So test for quit after the first one. Refactoring would give you something like this:

```
loop do
    puts "enter each number then hit enter quit to end"
    number1 = STDIN.gets
    number1.chomp!
    exit if number1 == "quit"
    number2 = STDIN.gets
    number2.chomp!
    number3 = STDIN.gets
    number3.chomp!

    numbers = [number1,number2,number3]
    if number1 > number2 or number1 > number3
        puts "Integers close"
    elsif number2 < number3
        puts"Integers far"
    end
end
```

Use `chomp` instead of `chop`, since the latter arbitrarily removes the last character while the former is specifically designed to remove `\n` and `\r`.